# Expected idle time of a server in an M/M/N queue

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, operations-research, queueing-theory

Consider a standard M/M/N queue where the jobs' arrival rate is $N\lambda$, the service rate of each of the $N$ servers is $1$, and $\lambda < 1$.

When a new job arrives, assign it to an idle server with the longest idle time. I would like to ask, in the steady state, what is the expected idle time of a server once when it becomes idle? Specifically, does the expected idle time goes to zero as $N$ goes to infinity?

Comment: And what is the assignment rule if there is no idle server at the moment?

Comment: @fedja If there is no idle server, the jobs (served in FCFS order) have to wait till one server becomes idle.

Comment: In that case does the first server who becomes free count this as an event of becoming idle with idle time 0, or is considered to be busy?

Comment: @fedja We will count this as an event of becoming idle with idle time 0.

Comment: Then the answer becomes trivial $(1-\lambda)/\lambda$ pretty much independently of the assignment rule assuming that the assignment rule guarantees the symmetry between the servers.